# My Wordpress Editor will bold text but once published, there is no formatting

Tags: css, wordpress

In both Microsoft Edge and Chrome, bold text shows up in my Wordpress Editor but not the actual post itself.

Example:
[image]

In Published Post: [Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5bw3.png)
[image]

It might be an issue with my style sheet overriding the WP Editor, but every other fix I've tried doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add this to theme stylesheet:

strong{font-weight:bold!important;}

Comment: That didn't work. I've tried that before.

Comment: Post the HTML output of the bolded text and its style using 'inspect element'

Comment: <p><span id="more-380"></span></p>
<p><b>Characters:</b> Elena and Clay Danvers (always need a good werewolf pack), Casey Duncan (detective and human), Harry Potter (you can always use a brave wizard), Kaz Brekker (can always get his way out of trouble)</p>
<p><strong>Location</strong>: Road Trip across Scotland</p>

Comment: Any help?! I know it's my theme overriding wordpress on the bold. Everything else works, I just don't know what is overriding wordpress to change it.